# Magento 2: Logged-in customer can't place order with new shipping module

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, shipping

The logged-in customer can't place an order with the custom shipping module

gives warning msg and can't process due to Please specify a shipping method

But the guest user can place an order without a problem.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: @Charul, have you face the issue or do you know what is causing the issue?

Comment: I did not faced this one but i think it is issue in your custom shipping module you please try to check at that scenario when you are choosing shipping method and go into that shipping module code may be you can get exact reason why it is happening.